# Writing and Formatting and Tips on Poetry

Tags: poetry

As a person trying to write poetry, I always have a problem trying to get subject material(especially for the past six months) and formatting it, or trying to put it to specific forms like a verse. Also, I seem to have a problem with keeping on point with the main topic of the poem, and I seem to go off with imagery to the point where it can be jumbled. I believe this came from both of my creative writing classes because we never went in depth on fiction, writing, poetry, rules, genres, ect.

If I may ask without trying to sound like a previously asked question, what are some tips from  you all? Am I over-thinking everything or confused or what?

I apologize if I sound like another inquiry into the matter. Thank you so much for taking the time to read this, as I am brand new to this site.

Comment: I think this question might be too broad. Can you try to focus it a little more? Are you having trouble with the **subject** or the **form**? Can you describe the style that you're aiming for? Poetry is terribly diverse. Without knowing the effect you're going for, it's hard to give tips that would be helpful. What works for one style is completely wrong for another.

Comment: _Personal experience here in my comment (since I haven't studies about poetry, but I get my self-published poetry book)_ I suggest you use all that you got written so far "lines, thoughts, verses, etc" and later just focused in **what you're _trying_ to express** and take each piece of line (or even, create new ones) and if you did put emotions or meaning to those lines, your inspiration will guide you to _build_ some poems. The first paragraph and the first two points of @Pavel Janicek's answer are good points to start to IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am (co)author of one self-published poem issue called *Havran Blije* (Raven vomits in English), I will describe you the creative process behind it:

**1. Being disgusted:** So many new poem authors do not care about rythm or rhyme. They just "vomit" whatever feeling they have on the paper and thats it

**2. Being in community which poems. A lot** And they exactly post poems in form of [free verse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_verse) which is just the random thoughts they have:

*Its sunny down in the park*

*I have good feelings from it*

*Found chesnut, lying on the ground*

*And there is vomitting raven*

**3. Idea!** What if. What if people, who care about the [true poems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman) gathered together and output together something, what cares about rhyme, form and the whole structure of poems?

**4. Even stupider idea:** What if we show this on poems which are not "deep" in any sense of the word, but its still perfected in matter of form?

**5. Even stupider idea:** Wow, one of the grup member can draw!

**6. Gather around and have fun about the stupid ideas we just had**

**7. Write them down and perfect the poems, so that they have correct form**. We have [haiku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haiku) in correct form, We have one poem in [iambic pentameter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iambic_pentameter) (which is totally hardcore to do in Czech language) and many more.

**8. Publish** [ta-da](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16113300/Havran%20blije.pdf)!

[image: raven vomits]

Hope it answers the question

Comment: might one ask what "blinky blinky" translates to in English?

Comment: If a child says in Czech that (s)he needs to puke, they will say "blinkat" and "blinky blinky" is what you say if you had bad food, or you feel bad in the stomach. Basically: "Child way how to describe sound of puking."

And to answer next question, yes, the poor raven is puking, vomiting or throwing up in every single poem

Comment: Is the book subtitled *Poems to Piss Off Odin and Edgar Allen Poe*?

Comment: @LaurenIpsum *Then this tiresome bird beguiling my pained fancy into smiling, --- By the grave and stern decorum of the countenance it wore, --- "Though thy songs be long and brazen, thou" I said "art sure no craven, --- Ghastly grim and tedious Raven, casting words across the floor, --- Tell me where thy lordly works hath spewed outward to vex and bore.  --- Quoth the Raven "Nevermore."*

Comment: @Ynneadwraith  “Hey," said Shadow. "Huginn or Muninn, or whoever you are."
The bird turned, head tipped, suspiciously, on one side, and it stared at him with bright eyes. "Say 'Nevermore,' " said Shadow. "Fuck you," said the raven.” ― Neil Gaiman, *American Gods*